# How to properly delete music file in SD card and how to create new file?

Tags: android

I have created one folder and some JSON file in SD card via programmatically, It's creating the folder and file no problem, But it's showing only on mobile file directory, It's not showing in the system after connecting my mobile to the system. if I copy and paste the same folder in mobile then it's showing in the system the copied folder only original folder not yet showing. for reference, I have added my mobile and system directory images.

[here in mobile original and copied folders are showing](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ENlqw.jpg)

[here only copied folder only showing](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IpgWM.png)

Same like that, some music files I have in SD card, that one I am trying to delete.

> path = (sdcard file path ) 
>   File SongFile = new File(path);
>   songFile.delete();

This function deletes the file correctly on my SD card.
But after deleting also in my system it's showing if I trying to play its showing some error. This deleted file not deleted properly. After delete also I am getting the same file programmatically in my application.

In my application also showing deleted files name and details.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suspect that you didn't delete the entry from the Media Store and this is the reason why you still see it.

- Get the `_id` of the entry searching it by `data` parameter with a
  `ContentResolver`
- Delete the entry using the above `_id`

Here a snippet:

```
public void deleteFromMediaStore(Context context, String pathToDelete) {
        ContentResolver contentResolver = context.getContentResolver();
        if (contentResolver != null) {
            Cursor matchingIndex = contentResolver.query(Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI, new String[]{"_id", "_data"}, "_data = ?", new String[]{pathToDelete}, null);

            if(matchingIndex != null && matchingIndex.getCount() > 0) {
                matchingIndex.moveToFirst();
                while (!matchingIndex.isAfterLast()) {
                    context.getContentResolver().delete(ContentUris.withAppendedId(Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI, (long) matchingIndex.getInt(matchingIndex.getColumnIndex("_id"))), null, null);
                    matchingIndex.moveToNext();
                }
                matchingIndex.close();
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for your reply. Now it's deleting properly and delete function working fine.

Comment: I have created one folder and some JSON file in SD card via programmatically, It's creating the folder and file no problem, But it's showing only on mobile file directory, It's not showing in the system after connecting my mobile to the system. if I copy and paste the same folder in mobile then it's showing in the system the copied folder only original folder not yet showing. for reference, I have added my mobile and system directory images. In my question, I have added reference images

Comment: @RegunathSiva I think you should not worry about this, it's pretty common. Reboot the device and show show fine